# How to resolve this issue: panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

Tags: go

After running again and again I am getting sometimes this issue. I know it's related to counter related. When the Done() method of a sync.WaitGroup is called more times than the Add() method was called then it will throw this error.

How do I fix this?

My code created batches of size 4 and do some processing on each batch but I am getting issue with resolving this panic.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    // create input channel
    input := make(chan int)

    // create wait group
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // start batcher goroutine
    wg.Add(1)
    go batcher(input, &wg)

    // send input values to the batcher
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        input <- i
    }

    // close input channel
    close(input)

    // wait for batcher goroutine to finish
    wg.Wait()
}

func batcher(input chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // create batch channel with buffer of size 4
    batch := make(chan int, 4)

    // create channel to synchronize worker goroutines
    done := make(chan bool)

    // create wait group for worker goroutines
    var workerWg sync.WaitGroup

    // start worker goroutines
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        workerWg.Add(1)
        go worker(batch, &workerWg, done)
    }

    // read input values and send to batch
    for value := range input {
        batch <- value
        if len(batch) == 4 {
            // wait for worker goroutines to finish processing batch
            workerWg.Wait()

            // send batch to worker goroutines
            for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
                workerWg.Add(1)
                go sendBatch(batch, &workerWg, done)
            }
        }
    }

    // wait for worker goroutines to finish processing remaining batch
    workerWg.Wait()

    // close done channel to notify that all batches have been processed
    close(done)

    wg.Done()
}

func sendBatch(batch chan int, workerWg *sync.WaitGroup, done chan bool) {
    // process batch
    for value := range batch {
        fmt.Println("Processing value:", value)
    }

    // notify worker goroutines that batch has been processed
    workerWg.Done()

    select {
    case done <- true:
    default:
        // done channel has been closed
    }
}

func worker(batch chan int, workerWg *sync.WaitGroup, done chan bool) {
    // process batches received from batch channel
    for batch := range batch {
        // process batch
        fmt.Println("Processing batch:", batch)
        workerWg.Done()
    }

    // notify batcher goroutine that worker goroutine has finished
    select {
    case done <- true:
    default:
        // done channel has been closed
    }
}
```

Basic code to write batcher:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    input := make(chan int)
    output := make(chan []int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    // Start the batcher goroutine
    go func() {
        batch := []int{}
        for value := range input {
            batch = append(batch, value)
            if len(batch) == 4 {
                output <- batch
                batch = []int{}
            }
        }
        if len(batch) > 0 {
            output <- batch
        }
        close(output)
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // Start the worker goroutine
    go func() {
        for batch := range output {
            sum := 0
            for _, value := range batch {
                sum += value
            }
            fmt.Printf("Sum of batch %v: %d\n", batch, sum)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // Send input values to the batcher
    for _, v := range []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} {
        input <- v
    }
    close(input)

    // Wait for both goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
}
```

```
Sum of batch [1 2 3 4]: 10
Sum of batch [5 6 7 8]: 26
Sum of batch [9 10]: 19
```

Earlier design was bit complicated I will try to extend this basic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this code:

```
for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
    workerWg.Add(1)
    go worker(batch, &workerWg, done)
}
```

I think `workerWg.Done()` should be moved outside of the loop:

```
  func worker(batch chan int, workerWg *sync.WaitGroup, done chan bool) {
+   defer workerWg.Done()
    // process batches received from batch channel
    for batch := range batch {
        // process batch
        fmt.Println("Processing batch:", batch)
-       workerWg.Done()
    }

    // notify batcher goroutine that worker goroutine has finished
    select {
    case done <- true:
    default:
        // done channel has been closed
    }
  }
```

But `batch` is not closed in the demo. So in fact, the goroutine will run for ever until the program is ended.

I'm not sure whether there is any other issue. The design is too complicated. Complicated code is hard to understand and prone to error. Consider redesigning it.

Comment: Yes I tried moving out as well but sometimes on re run still get the error. I guess it's because of using too many go routine inside one another.

Comment: Have you closed `batch` anywhere? Since it's not closed in the demo, If `worker` is modified as shown in my answer, The first `workerWg.Wait()` will block forever.

Comment: And there is not read from the unbuffered chan `done`, which looks abnormal. I believe you are trying to provide a minimal reproducer, but it seems that this demo does not reflect your real situation. I still insist that you should try to simplify the design.

Comment: Actually this is the original code I am using to learn the concepts :(. Kinda noob at concurrency.

Comment: I will create a new code for implementing batcher then

Comment: Here are two talks on go concurrency that could be helpful: https://go.dev/talks/2012/concurrency.slide#1 https://go.dev/blog/io2013-talk-concurrency

Comment: Thanks Zeke If you have more blogs or resources on go please do share.

Comment: Sorry but I don't. If you want to learn more, I would recommend you to follow the [golang issues](https://github.com/golang/go/issues). You will meet the creators of golang and other smart people there.